# how to check if checkbox checked using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, pseudo-element

I have such element as span, which looks like checkbox. The main check box is hidden and is not displayed.
In Developer tool of Edge the checkbox looks like:
[image: checkBox]

In Developer tool of Edge the element looks like:
[image: In Developer tool of Edge it looks like:]

on a web page this element unchecked looks:

[image: element on a web page unchecked]

and checked :

[image]

How can I check if the checkbox checked using Java Selenium. I need to make some tests of these checkboxes using Selenium.
But when I tried to use `checkbox.isChecked()` it didn't checked, because it is not a check box.
Then I tried to use Developer Tools of browser and found that nothing changing when I check\uncheck the checkbox. the checkbox itself is not displayed.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: You need to add the HTML where the actual checkbox icon is displayed. My guess is that contains a CSS style, etc. applied so that you can tell when it is or isn't checked.

Comment: Post url for more help. Doesnt CHECKBOX changes some attribute when is checked and when is not checked?? (the attribute checked)

Comment: it is little bit hard to provide the code as typed code. Because I dont have the source. It was as my test work... and finally i managed to realize the checked and unchecked checkbox. I dont why while checking and unchecking the checkboxes there were no changes in developer tools in Edge. but may be this is my bad that i didnt check in other browsers....may be I had to check other cases...

Comment: I managed it with `JavascriptExecutor`. Using the javascriptexecutor I just checked the checkbox and checked if webpage will pass to next step.

Answer (score -1):

May be it will help somebody. Here is how I checked the checkbox :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String clickCheckBox1 = "let elem = document.evaluate(\"//*[@id='tab-1']/div[5]/label[1]/span\",document, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;elem.click();";
js.executeScript(clickCheckBox1);
Helpers.wait(1);
String clickCheckBox2 = "let elem2 = document.evaluate(\"//*[@id='tab-1']/div[5]/label[2]/span\",document, null,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;elem2.click();";
js.executeScript(clickCheckBox2);
```

`Helpers.wait(1);` is the custom class, which makes just `Thread.sleep(ms)` :

```
public static void wait(int seconds){
        try{
            int i = seconds * 1000;
            Thread.sleep(i);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```